# Google Cloud Vision vs ImageIdentify

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

Google has recently made their vision API publicly available (in beta release). I was hoping someone who has access to it could speak to how it compares with *Mathematica*'s `ImageIdentify` functionality.

What types of metadata can these two image recognition systems yield, what and how many tags are supported, etc...

Comment: Why the close votes?